# Why does the Node.js scripts console close instantly in Windows 8?

Tags: node.js, windows-8, console-application

I've tried nearly every example for scripts I can find. Every sample opens the terminal for a split second. Even this closes as soon as input is entered. Is this normal?

```
    var rl = require('readline');

var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

prompts.question("How many servings of fruits and vegetables do you eat each day? ", function  (servings) {
    var message = '';

    if (servings < 5) {
        message = "Since you're only eating " + servings + 
        " right now, you might want to start eating " + (5 - servings) + " more.";
    } else {
        message = "Excellent, your diet is on the right track!";
    }

    console.log(message);

  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that control this in Tools/Options/Node.js Tools/General:

Wait for input when process exists abnormally 
Wait for input when process exists normally

Taken from https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/discussions/565665