# How to get node.js console to pause in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2017, console

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the built in tools support for node.js. I want to be able to create a empty console node.js project and run the debugger and see the console window output.

However, when I run it, it opens the console and runs the script so quickly I cannot see what it is doing.

I have followed previous questions ([Node.js console gets closed immediately after i execute the program from Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503001/node-js-console-gets-closed-immediately-after-i-execute-the-program-from-visual))

and have gone into Tools > Options > Node.js and have all three options checked:

Wait for input when process exits abnormally

Wait for input when process exits normally

Enable Edit and Continue

Although I have all three options checked, The behavior does not change. Could someone please help?

thanks

Comment: What happens if you use ctrl+f5 to run the application? Does the console app stay alive?

Answer (score 4):

I tried, 
It works with **ctrl + F5**
After checking all three options in debug -> options -> Node.js Tools