# JavaScript Keep Console Window Open in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, console, visual-studio-2017

I'm working through Basarat Ali Syed's book "Beginning Node.js", and I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (not to be confused with Visual Studio Code). I like the fact that I can view output in a console window that pops up, rather than having to go through the browser.

However, when I run through code like the following, the console window pops up and closes before I have a chance to see the result. I know how to keep the console window open in C# (Console.Read()), but this is JavaScript.

How do I keep the console window open with the following code?

```

```
function getConnection(callback) {
    var connection;
    try {
        throw new Error('connection failed');

        callback(null, connection);
    }
    catch (error) {

        callback(error, null);
    }
}

getConnection(function (error, connection) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error.message);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connection succeeded:', connection);
    }
});
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that ctrl + f5 will open a console that stays open. Interestingly, there are two similar questions on stackoverflow about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503001/node-js-console-gets-closed-immediately-after-i-execute-the-program-from-visual) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731442/why-does-the-node-js-scripts-console-close-instantly-in-windows-8), but the "solution" does not work in my Windows 10 / VS 2017 environment. I'll stick with using ctrl + f5, or running `node filename.js` in a terminal window.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed seem broken in VS 2017, your solution worked!

Answer (score 2):

I'm starting out with JavaScript using Visual Studio 2019 and node.js in Windows 10. Using Ctrl + F5 (Start without debugging) keeps the console open until I press a key.

Note, the "Wait for input when process exits normally" option for Node.js Tools must also be checked.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment to the question than an answer itself. Once you have achieved a certain number of rep point you will be able to make comments in other questions/answers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com please read how to write good answer guide from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer